# Go async/await pattern with context cancellation

Tags: go, async-await

In my application I need async/await pattern with context cancellation support. In practice I have a function like:

```
func longRunningTask() <-chan int32 {
    r := make(chan int32)

    go func() {
        defer close(r)
        
        // Simulate a workload.
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 3)
        r <- rand.Int31n(100)
    }()

    return r
}
```

However, it will not support context cancellation. In order to fix this, I can add an argument and modify function to wait for `ctx.Done()` channel signal in a select statement, to abort an operation if context is cancelled.

If done this way, the function will not properly abort if run twice or more times (because the context pointer will be shared), since context cancellation channel only receives *one* signal:

```
ctx := ...
go func() { r := <-longRunningTask(ctx) } // Done() works
go func() { r := <-longRunningTask(ctx) } // ?
// cancel() ...
```

Here is what I see about Done:

```
   // go/context.go

   357  func (c *cancelCtx) Done() <-chan struct{} {
   358      c.mu.Lock()
   359      if c.done == nil {
   360          c.done = make(chan struct{})
   361      }
   362      d := c.done
   363      c.mu.Unlock()
   364      return d
   365  } // Done() returns the same channel for all callers, and cancellation signal is sent once only
```

1. Does the go source mean `context` does not really support abortion of a function that calls other "long-running" functions, "a chained cancellation"?
2. What are options to write asynchronious functions that will support context cancellation in an unlimited recursion of `.Done()` usage?

Comment: The context `done` channel is closed on cancelation. No values are sent to the channel.

Comment: If multiple goroutines select on ctx.Done(), all goroutines will get the done signal, because when context is canceled, done channel is closed.

Comment: It's not your question, but your `longRunningTask` could just return an `int32` rather than a channel. `func longRunningTask(ctx context.Context) int32 { time.Sleep(3 * time.Second); return rand.Int31n(100) }` (although you probably also need a waitgroup to do the final join, but you do anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Does the go source mean context does not really support abortion of a
>    function that calls other "long-running" functions, "a chained
>    cancellation"?

No. A task can call other long-running tasks, passing a context down the call chain. This is a standard practice. And if a context is canceled, a nested call will error and bubble-up the cancelation error along the call stack

> 2. What are options to write asynchronious functions that will support context cancellation in an unlimited recursion of .Done() usage?

Recursion is no different that a couple of nested calls that take a context. Provided the recursive calls take a context input parameter and return an error (that is check), a recursive call chain will bubble-up a cancelation event just like a set of non-recursive nested calls.

---

First, let's update your wrapper function to support `context.Context`:

```
func longRunningTask(ctx context.Context) <-chan int32 {
    r := make(chan int32)

    go func() {
        defer close(r)
        
        // workload
        i, err := someWork(ctx)
        if err != nil {
            return
        }
        r <- i
    }()

    return r
}
```

And then `someWork` - to use the sleep workload would look like this:

```
func someWork(ctx context.Context) (int32, error) {

    tC := time.After(3*time.Second) // fake workload

    // we can check this "workload" *AND* the context at the same time
    select {
    case <-tC:
        return rand.Int31n(100), nil
    case <-ctx.Done():
        return 0, ctx.Err()
    }
}
```

The important thing to note here is, we can alter the fake "workload" (time.Sleep) in a way that it becomes a channel - and thus watch it and our context via a `select` statement. Most workloads are of course not this trivial...

Fortunately the Go standard library is full of support for `context.Context`. So if your workload consists of lots of potentially long-running SQL query, each query can be passed a context. Same with HTTP requests or gRPC calls. If your workload consists of any of these calls, passing in the parent context will cause any of these potentially blocking calls to return with an error when the context is canceled - and thus your workload will return with a cancellation error, letting the caller know what happened.

If your workload does not fit neatly into this model e.g. computing a large Mandelbrot-Set image. Checking the context for cancelation after every pixel can have negative performance impact as polling selects are not free:

```
select {
case <-ctx.Done(): // polling select when `default` is included
    return ctx.Err()
default:
}
```

In cases like this, tuning could be applied and if say pixels are calculated at a rate of 10,000/s - polling the context every 10,000 pixels will ensure the task will return no later than 1 second from the point of cancelation.

Comment: Using selects the way you shown in the `someWork()` is rather trivial. My concern is that the function is blocking. My question was about specific function signature - that returns channel for result, async, what is similar to the async/await pattern in some languages, and what I am thinking of for an API.

Comment: @Croll if I'm making a potentially block request using a 3rd party library e.g. [go-ldap](https://godoc.org/github.com/go-ldap/ldap) which does *NOT* have any `context.Context` hooks - then I'll wrap cancelation into these calls. Since canceling a request a request may leave residue on the active connection, in my context-wrapper call, I will close the connection - so other calls do not get half-baked result. This is not ideal, as connections can be shared and used concurrently - but without rewriting the third-party package, it's the next best solution.

Comment: this is interesting. Could you share a hint how you would cancel a blocking connection? Thanks